# Is there an R function to return a parameter in a list that can not be find by str(list)

Tags: r

I’m trying to return a parameter in a list, but I cannot find the parameter using `str(list)`.

this is my codes

```
install.packages("meta")
library(meta)
m1 <- metacor(c(0.85, 0.7, 0.95), c(20, 40, 10))
m1
     COR           95%-CI %W(fixed) %W(random)
1 0.8500 [0.6532; 0.9392]      27.9       34.5
2 0.7000 [0.4968; 0.8304]      60.7       41.7
3 0.9500 [0.7972; 0.9884]      11.5       23.7


Number of studies combined: k = 3


                       COR           95%-CI    z  p-value
Fixed effect model   0.7955 [0.6834; 0.8710] 8.48 < 0.0001
Random effects model 0.8427 [0.6264; 0.9385] 4.87 < 0.0001
```

how could I save `COR`(=0.8427) or`p-value`(=< 0.0001) for`Random effects model` as  a single  parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the numbers that you are looking for (cor 0.8427) are created in `print.meta`. The function seems too big though so I gave up trying to pinpoint exactly where it gets calculated and what name it has. I don't think it is even saved within the function, but rather printed.

Anyway I took the alternative road of capturing the output:

```
#capture the output of the summary - the fifth line gives us what we want
out <- capture.output(summary(m1))[5]
#capture all the number and return the first
unlist(regmatches(out, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*", out)))[1]
#[1] "0.8427"
```

Comment: this function`unlist(regmatches(out, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*", out)))[1]` remove `-`, then returns negative value as positive values.
I made some modification
`out=capture.output(summary(m1))[5]`
`out=gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9;,._-]"," ", out)`
`out=gsub("[;]"," ", out)`
`out=strsplit(out, "\\s+")[[1]]`
`as.numeric(c(out[4],out[8])`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is accessing to the object. 
The `$` will help you with it, such that by putting the variablename, then the dollar and by pressing the tab, the different possibilities of that object will appear. According to you questions, the values would be

```
> m1$cor[1]
[1] 0.85
> mysummary<-summary(m1)
> mysummary$fixed$p
[1] 2.163813e-17
> mysummary$fixed$z
[1] 8.484643
> ifelse(mysummary$fixed$p<0.0001, "<0.0001", "WHATEVER")
[1] "<0.0001"
```

To select a specific one, you can use `[i]` where i is an integer (example i = 1 for 0.85)
To get a 0.0001, I suggest using an `ifelse()` statement on pvalues or Z with their according rule. Cheers !